# Modifying HTML textarea as the user types?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you manipulate text inside of a textarea as the user types in it?

Comment: The text in the textarea isn't modified as the user types.  Rather, the preview window is modified.  Are you talking about the preview window or the "toolbar" buttons above the post area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use the `onKeyUp` event to detect key presses, then use the `value` property of the textarea to get and/or set the value.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function change_text() {
        // get the text
        text = document.getElementById("your_textarea").value;

        // ...

        // set the text
        document.getElementById("your_textarea").value = text;
    }
</script>

...

<textarea id="your_textarea" onKeyUp="change_text()"></textarea>
```